# Which one is better performance wise?

Tags: operation

Performance wise, which is better:

a. filesizeInMB = filesize / (1024 * 1024)

or

b. filesizeInMB = filesize / 1024 / 1024

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is often better to avoid division. Thus a would be better.

On the other hand. If your compiler is smart. It could maybe see that dividing by 1024 is equal to a bit shifting operation. In that case b could be even faster.

Comment: Thank you, I guess the first line cleared what we were looking for.